# Where did the profile images go?

Tags: support, gravatar

Currently as I am browsing Server Fault I see pages looking like this:

[image]

As you can see most of the profile images have disappeared. Right clicking on a broken image and choosing to see the image in a new tab greets me with a 403 error with no useful explanation.

What may have caused this, and is there something I could do myself to make it work again?

Comment: Were these http imgs that got converted to https?

Comment: Works for me, even with a cold browser cache These images are supplied by an external service (Gravatar, a Wordpress/automattic service), so I guess there is not much SE can do about this and the problem lies between you and Gravatar. The images that *are* working come from SE's imgur subservice.

Comment: @84104 The images were being accessed over https, and I think that has been the case for a while without problems.

Comment: @Sven The images are loading again for me.

Comment: I did a report some time ago on MSE, for problem with avatar, not the same trouble but MSE told me it was gravatar issues , like sven told (https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/291812/icon-bug-for-some-badges-winner)